# Blessed / Curses controls don't work with Pyinstaller. Missing vtwin10

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller, curses, blessed

I have a very simple Python program that uses 'Blessed'.  It works fine with the Win10 Python interpreter, but reports an error when packaged with Pyinstaller, and terminal control codes are ignored.  Here's the code:

```
from blessed import Terminal
t = Terminal()
print(t.bright_green('Hello world'))
```

The string 'Hello world' is supposed to display on the console in bright green.  Pyinstaller completes with no errors, and when I run the .exe, I get the message:

> terminal.py:222: UserWarning: Failed to setupterm(kind='vtwin10'): Could not find terminal vtwin10

and then 'Hello world' is displayed in default terminal color.

It looks like Pyinstaller isn't including something in the build that the interpreter finds without issue.  I found a vtwin10.py file in my Anaconda3 installation folder at:

> C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jinxed\terminfo

I looked at the referenced error in the blessed library's terminal.py file.  Here's the code:

```
            try:
                curses.setupterm(self._kind, self._init_descriptor)
            except curses.error as err:
                warnings.warn('Failed to setupterm(kind={0!r}): {1}'
                              .format(self._kind, err))
```

So it looks like self._kind is being set to 'vtwin10'.  There is a conditional import in terminal.py that looks like this:

```
if platform.system() == 'Windows':
    import jinxed as curses  # pylint: disable=import-error
    HAS_TTY = True
```

(I get the humor.)  It looks like the jinxed package is being imported explicitly in the code, and replaces the curses package.  But somehow the vtwin10 definition is missing.

I found setupterm() in jinxed and dug deeper to find where that error message is coming from.  It's in this code:

```
        try:
            self.terminfo = importlib.import_module('jinxed.terminfo.%s' % term.replace('-', '_'))
        except ImportError:
            raise error('Could not find terminal %s' % term)
```

This is where I get stuck.  It looks like this code is unable to find the vtwin10.py file in the jinxed library.  Does anyone know how to force Pyinstaller to include the vtwin10 terminal definition for curses?  I'm guessing this is the problem.

Many thanks.

Comment: Just a guess, but try adding `jinxed` as a hidden import when you run `pyinstaller`.

Comment: As you suggested, I tried:

"pyinstaller --hidden-import jinxed --onefile test.py"

and got the same message and results.  During the build, only INFO messages were shown.

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured this out.  In the jinxed library, the code line:

```
importlib.import_module('jinxed.terminfo.%s' % term.replace('-', '_'))
```

dynamically loads a library module.  Pyinstaller can't package dynamically imported modules.  So to fix this, I need to specify the module using the --hidden-import option.  The syntax is as follows:

```
pyinstaller --hidden-import=jinxed.terminfo.vtwin10 --onefile test.py
```

Program works just like in the interpreter.  It works, but I'm concerned this breaks any platform independence `jinxed` was supposed to have.  I can force import the `vtwin10.py` module, and it will work on `win10` platforms.  But the way `jinxed` is written, it figures out the windows platform and then dynamically loads the required `terminfo` module.  There are a number of them in the `jinxed.terminfo` directory.  Wildcards for `--hidden-import` don't work, so the only option is to use `--hidden-import` for every file in the `jinxed.terminfo` folder.

Answer (score 1):

For now you will only need to specify `jinxed.terminfo.vtwin10` and `jinxed.terminfo.ansicon` on Windows, but if you want it to be more dynamic, pyinstaller spec files are executable Python, so you can just dynamically look up any terminfo modules.

```
import pkgutil
import jinxed.terminfo
hiddenimports = [mod.name for mod in pkgutil.iter_modules(jinxed.terminfo.__path__, 'jinxed.terminfo.')
```